# A finite automaton accept no string

Tags: automata, finite-automata

How can a finite automaton over(0,1) doesn't accept any string? I only can think of

```
s->a->q->F
```

Where the final state F is empty set. Is that true please?

Comment: Not the final state is the empty set, but there are no final states.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How to draw that If there is no final state please? Is it the only answer?

Comment: How do you draw the a non-final state?

Comment: So in the symbol I showed above, should I delete F and claim there is no final state, would it be the answer please?

Comment: Do you know what a finite automaton looks like? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A finite automaton does not accept any string if and only if all its final states are unreachable from the start state.

This is true if there is no final state, or if you cannot go from the start state to the final state.

Comment: Thanks for reply. So in my case, is there a way to make final state "unreachable" please?

Comment: Take your favourite automata. If you remove all the accepting states, then you obtain an automata which does not accept any string.

Comment: The minimal example would be an automata made of only one non-accepting state.

Comment: non-accepting state is just initial state, is that correct please?

Comment: Yes that's correct.